# Parcelable: read/write of a list of a subclass of a object that is parcelable

Tags: java, android

I know the title seems a little bit misunderstanding but anyway...

I have a class that implements Parcelable

```
class A implements Parcelable{
 // parcelable implementation
}
```

Then class B extends A

```
class B extends A{
 // parcelable implementation
}
```

And a class C implements Parcelable also

```
class C implement Parcelable{
    // A interesting list
    List<A> items;

    public void addItems(){
        items.add(new A());<<OK
        items.add(new A());<<OK
        items.add(new B());<<OK but NOT
    }

    // read
    protected C(Parcel in) {
        items= in.createTypedArrayList(A.CREATOR);
    }
    // write
    ...
    dest.writeTypedList(items);
}
```

The problem is because the List items is a list a A object and it also accept B object, when reading/writing I get the wrong value and Outofmemory also.
I notice the writeToParcel of the B class is called when writing but the protected constructor (protected B(Parcel in)...) of B is never called when reading. That caused my app gete crashed when unparcel.

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: protected is meaning it can only reach by its subclase.

Comment: it doesn't matter ... Parcelable use reflection ... with `in.createTypedArrayList(A.CREATOR)` line you point to use `A.CREATOR` for every item in the list ... you can't do this without saving class of the class and using right CREATOR

Comment: @Selvin:"saving class of the class and using right CREATOR". Could you please provide more detail?. How can I point to the right class, (the B class in above)? Thanks

Comment: i meant ... instead writeTypedList you have to in the loop for each items parcel the class of item (or CREATOR) parcel the item itself .... then when unparceling .. you have to (in the loop) unparcel the class then using reflection unparcel the item ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggess but I think there must be a better way. :3

Comment: No, there is no ... Parcelable is not inheritance wise ... how on hell createTypedArrayList would know that at position k item is not A but B? ... `createTypedArrayList` is dumb ... you pass the CREATOR and it use it for every item.... even if you try somthing like calling some overiden method(inside constructor) the class loader would not know to create class B and use the one from base class (A)